Let $\{\vec{x}_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be convergent, show that $\{\vec{x}_k:k\in \Bbb N\}\cup\{\vec{x}\}$ is a compact set.
Let $\{\vec{x}_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in $\Bbb R^n$ that converges to the vector $\vec{x}\in \Bbb R^n$, then show that $\{\vec{x}_k:k\in \Bbb N\}\cup\{\vec{x}\}$ is a compact set.
According to Heine-Borel, a set is said to be compact iff is closed and bounded.
So, $\{\vec{x}_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ converges and because of that, $\{\vec{x}_k:k\in \Bbb N\}$  is bounded. Now, note that the set $\{\vec{x}_k:k\in \Bbb N\}$ is closed, for $\vec{x}\in\{\vec{x}_k:k\in \Bbb N\}$. Knowing that $\vec{x}$ is a limit point of the set $\{\vec{x}_k:k\in \Bbb N\}$ such that $\vec{x}\in\{\vec{x}_k:k\in \Bbb N\}$, and by definition, a closed set contains all its limit points, so $\{\vec{x}_k:k\in \Bbb N\}$ is a closed set.
Now, considering $\{\vec{x}_k:k\in \Bbb N\}\cup\{\vec{x}\}$, we get $\{\vec{x}_k:k\in \Bbb N\}$. And so, the set $\{\vec{x}_k:k\in \Bbb N\}\cup\{\vec{x}\}$ is compact in $\Bbb R^n$.
Does my proof works? If not, let me know  if something's missing . Thanks!

A couple of things: a) you haven't addressed boundedness, and b) you've observed that $\vec{x}$ is a limit point of ${\vec{x}_k : k \in \Bbb{N}}$, but how do you know there are no other limit points?

It'll be because the unicity of the limit. And for boundedness, we know that the set is bounded because the sequence from where it co0mes, is convergent. Does that could be enough?

Hard to say. Depending on who is grading you, this may be sufficient. I know that I would ideally want to know why the unicity of the limit of the sequence generating this set implies that this subset of $\Bbb{R}$ has no other limit points. If you have a result that says this, I would cite it (but I suspect you don't have a result that fits quite so neatly here). It's not that your intuition is wrong here, but there is still a logical gap. (The boundedness argument seems fine.)


Your proof of closedness is flawed indeed. 2) 'Heine-Borel' is a theorem.What is your definition of compactness?


The definition I work with is: $A\subseteq \Bbb R^n$, is said to be a compact set if it is possible to extract a finite subcover from a cover of $A$, such that it cover the set.

@Roma_Rayado In that case, you are probably best served by applying the definition directly. Hint: start with an arbitrary open cover, and choose your first open set $U_1$ from this cover to be any set containing $\vec{x}$. Note that $U_1$ may contain points of the sequence as well. What does convergence tell you about the points that are not contained in $U_1$?
